# how to check that my program is listening to port?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am new in Linux. I have started solr search engine  on locallhost:8080. when i am working on my PC, I can check it on internet browser by typing http://localhost:8080/solr and i can see its main page. 
now i have started it on server and access it by Bitvise ssh client. 
since i don't have any internet browser there(just terminal). so how can i  check that my program is started right? how can i see its main page and work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install / use `lynx` or `w3m` which are both terminal browsers.

`wget http://localhost:8080/solr` will grab the page too. That will save the data to a file.

You can try:

```
netstat -an | grep 8080
```

Or if `netstat` is deprecated (as noted by Centimane, see comment below) you should be able to use:

```
ss -an | grep 8080
```

You can use `telnet`. Some options are different between OS versions, but something like the following should work:

```
telnet localhost 8080
GET /solr HTTP/1.1
host: localhost
<enter>
```

This will dump the HTML / page to console.

There is often a short timeout between `GET` and `host:`, so you may have to type quick :]

Comment: Worth noting that on some newer systems like RHEL/CentOS 7 `netstat` is deprecated in favour of `ss`, which takes the same arguments. From `man netstat`: `This program is obsolete. Replacement for netstat is ss. Replacement for netstat -r is ip route. Replacement for netstat -i is ip -s link. Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr`

Comment: @Centimane Did not know that. Added an edit. Feel welcome to edit my answer too.

Comment: @Tigger `netstat` is still normally/commonly installed (or at least easily available) on systems where it's deprecated, so it's not incorrect to point to `netstat`. Presumably over time it will be phased out more and more, so it's best to use `ss` before `netstat` goes the way of the dinosaurs. I generally prefer suggesting changes in comments rather than highjacking someone's answer so long as they're an active user.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the program listen on particular port via command:

```
netstat -anp
```

and search for port or program name.

Also you can use curl or wget to check if the server answer:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solr
```